Are this many washers necessary?

I changed my brake pads. The old ones had a single bolt holding them on.
These new ones I bought have a bolt and a ton of washers. I thought maybe they were for size adjustment.
I just left them all on and it seems to be okay. Are there any downsides to this?

I'm guessing your old brake pads were much shorter too ?

I only just noticed that this is about a brake caliper and not a (mini) V-brake. I think they need different pads with much shorter bolts? The principle is the same but I think with brake calipers one of the convex surfaces is even integrated into the brake pad cartridge.

Yes, the original brake pads were shorter than these

They are not simple washers. They have a concave and convex shape which allows you to tilt the brake pad up and down and left and right (“toe in”). You need one pair on the inside and one on the outside. One pair has a thicker dull gray piece, one has a thinner one. You can choose which one to use on the inside or outside depending on your needs.
See:
Orders of the washers on threaded-stud brake shoes

So, could I just use one bolt and one washer like the original brake pads had?

You could but it’s probably not a good idea. Without the concave and convex washers (and in the correct order and place) your brake pads are exactly parallel to your brake arms. But usually you’ll want some toe-in and an “up” angle so when they hit the rim they are exactly at a 90° angle (when viewed from the front or rear). Without toe-in your brakes will probably shudder and squeal (and wear unevenly). Without the “up” angle they can slide down the brake track and unto the normal surface of the rim (as well as feeling spongy, wearing unevenly and generally bad performance).

Okay, I'll put them the way the diagram says in the link you provided.
Is there a significant difference between 4, 5, and 6mm spacing?

It depends on how wide your brakes are, how thick your pads are and how wide your rims are. Make sure you angle them correctly and they don’t contact the tyre or the normal surface of the rim. Can be a bit fiddly to set up.

I made sure the brakes didn't come into contact with the rubber tire, but what do you mean the "normal surface" of the rim? A quick Google search brings up mathematical graphs

I meant the non-braking surface i.e. the ordinary rim sidewalls without reinforcement for braking (brake track).

@John these pads were intended for V brakes, and the threaded portion might be too long to mount with fewer washers.  The nut on the end probably has a hex socket rather than going all the way through, so stacking washers might be required here.

I wasn't sure which type of brakes to buy. After hours of searching, I decided on these. Which type of brakes do I have in the picture? Is it fine to use these brake pads even if they were meant for V brakes? Thanks

@John yeah these should work fine - the extra length helps with braking, but exaggerates any misalignment problems.  The conical washers help with that by allowing you to get the alignment you want, when its not exactly  flat to the caliper's mounting point.  Just be careful the brake pad doesn't rub on the tyre when closed even as it wears down.

@John this Parktool page lists the different brake types and explains how you can identify your brake system. From your image it seems you have dual pivot or side pull calipers brakes (but I can be wrong, it's hard to identify it from this picture).
